# How do I hide an option in react-select

Tags: react-select

Basically i have two dropdowns. based on a value selected in one dropdown I want to hdie certain options in another dropdown.

I tried adding a className parameter to the option object along with label and value params and tried setting the display of all options with the above className to none but it did not set the className of the option to the one i specified.

```
[{'label':'x','value':'y',className:'hide'}]
.hide{
display:none
}
```

Comment: Hi @rohan-khanna, could you update your question and include a more detailed example of what you've tried so far and how is structured your file. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

According to https://react-select.com/props

> ###### filterOption
>
> Custom method to filter whether an option should be displayed in the menu

You just need to use `filterOption`
For example if you want to hide an option with *value="hiddenOption"* you need :

```
<Select filterOption={(option) => option.value !== "hiddenOption"} />
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do that using custom option, documentation for v2 is here:
https://react-select.com/components#replacing-components

But in your case, i think you should add some value to object list, for example:

{label: 'Example', value: '1234', shouldBeDisplayed:'false'}

Next step is customize custom option:

```html
const option = (props: OptionProps<any>) => (
  <div {...props.innerProps}>
    {props.data.shouldBeDisplayed? props.label : null}
  </div>
);
```

Using inside select:

```html
<Select components={{ Option: option }} ..... />
```

Hope it helps :)